# I have written some code in C++ using Octave API and this C++ function basically calls an Octave script, but it is giving segmentation fault

Tags: c++, octave

I want to write C++ code using Octave API for C++ which will use an Octave function. I am attaching my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <octave/oct.h>
#include <octave/octave.h>
#include <octave/parse.h>
#include <octave/toplev.h>
#include <interpreter.h>

int main()
{
        // arguments for octave
        string_vector argv (2);
        argv(0) = "embedded";
        argv(1) = "-q"; // quiet

        // start octave, run embedded (third parameter == true)
        octave_main (2, argv.c_str_vec (), true);

        // read the script file
        source_file("calc_and_plot.m");

        // call the function with an argument
        octave_value_list in;
        in(0) = "Hello, world.";
        feval("calc_and_plot", in);

        std::cout << "octave (child process) done\n";
        clean_up_and_exit(0); // quit octave. This also quits the program,
                              // so use this together with atexit, if you 
                              // need to do something else after octave exits
    
    return 0;
}
```

My Octave script file is:

```
function calc_and_plot(str)
    printf('%s\n', str);
    x = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
    y = sin(x);
    it = plot(y);
    waitfor(it);
end
```

I am getting **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**.
I execute the code using the terminal by running
"**mkoctfile --link-stand-alone file_name.cpp -L/usr/lib/octave-4.2.2 -I/usr/include/octave-4.0.2 -loctave -loctinterp -o file_name && ./file_name**".
I am using Octave 4.2.2 and it is installed in Ubuntu 18.04.
Please help me this this matter.

Comment: find a crash dump desymbolicate it (if needed) and paste it here.

Comment: Good, you simplified the program from your other question and thereby narrowed down to one of the problems. Did you try giving the `octave_value_list` a size before writing values to it, as I suggested in a comment to your other question? `octave_value_list in(1);` or something like that.

Comment: @Cris Luengo  segmentation fault (core dumped) occurs in "source_file("calc_and_plot.m");" line.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what's wrong with your code, but you seem to be mixing styles and libraries from different versions of octave.

E.g. toplev.h is deprecated in newer versions of octave, and has been replaced by interpreter.h. Yet you seem to be trying to include both headers ...

Equally, I think octave_main is no longer used (but maybe it was back in 4.2.2?)

Also from `-L/usr/lib/octave-4.2.2 -I/usr/include/octave-4.0.2` I can see you're trying mix octave v4.2.2 libraries with v4.0.2 headers, etc...   no wonder it's segfaulting!

---

Why are you even using such an old version of octave? The latest is 6.2.0. Do you have a particular reason for needing to use an older version?

If not, my advice would be to download and install the latest octave from source, and follow the instructions on how to create a standalone program from the manual here: https://octave.org/doc/v6.2.0/Standalone-Programs.html

If you require v4.2.2 specifically, then download and install *that* from source, and try to follow the instructions from the manual for *that* version specifically, e.g.: https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.2/Standalone-Programs.html

PS: note the changes in the manual between versions 4.02, 4.22, and 6.20 ... e.g. 4.02 uses toplev, but 4.22 does not! 4.22 uses octave_main, but 6.20 does not ...

Comment: No I don't have any particular reason to use the older version. I just want my work done, that could be in any version.

Comment: @SiddharthaRoy Great. In that case, I would recommend you download octave 6.2.0 from source, compile it, and read the relevant page in the latest manual.

Comment: please sir can you please tell me the steps to install octave 6.2.0 from source code because I got error and got some library issues and don't know how to overcome this. please help me to install octave 6.2.0 in ubuntu 18.04 properly.

Comment: @SiddharthaRoy The easiest thing to do is to run `sudo apt build-dep octave` first. This brings all the dependencies for octave 4.2.2. Yes this is an older version, but the dependencies are more or less the same. Then, decide on a location to install octave to, and make sure you have write-permissions. E.g. it could be `/home/siddhartha/.local/octave-6.2.0`. (Me, I gave `/opt` write-permissions, so I usually just install to `/opt/octave-6.2.0`; I'll use that as the example here). Then go to where you extracted the octave-6.2.0 sources, and type `./configure --prefix=/opt/octave-6.2.0`.

Comment: Then, if ./configure finishes and says it's ready to compile octave, you can run `make` (and let it finish ... this takes a while, minutes to hours really, depending on how powerful your machine is). When that finishes, run `make install` to install octave in the location you specified earlier under 'prefix'. If you chose a location that requires root permissions, you'll have to do `sudo make install` instead. (I usually give write permissions to the location I want so I don't need sudo). Octave is now installed, and you can run it by doing, e.g. `/opt/octave-6.2.0/bin/octave`

Comment: if you like, you can add the following line to your `.bashrc` file, to add octave's binary executables to the path: `PATH=/opt/octave-6.2.0/bin:$PATH`. After you close your terminal and reopen it (to activate a new session, which is initialised by reading the .bashrc file) then you'll be able to simply launch octave by typing `octave` in your terminal.

Comment: if the `./configure` step fails to complete and gives you an error, then typically this is because you're missing a library or something. Try to figure out which library you're missing and use `apt` to install it. Occasionally you need a tiny bit of detective work, but usually it just tells you up-front what library it is that you're missing.